# Merge two maps <string,int>

Tags: c++, dictionary

Suppose I have two maps

```
std::map<string,int> mapA;

mapA["cat"] = 1;
mapA["dog"] = 3;
```

then the other map is mapB

```
std::map<string,int> mapB;

mapB["cat"] = 1;
mapB["horse"] = 3;
```

Now I need to merge mapB into mapA
so the final mapA looks like this after merge

```
mapA["cat"] = 2;
mapA["dog"] = 3;
mapA["horse"] = 3;
```

I wanted to know what would the best way be to achieve this ?
I know that i could iterate through MapB and check if each element is in MapA if it is then increment the value otherwise Add it to MapA. My question is if there is an algorithm or a faster more efficient approach ?

Comment: An algorithm that could be more efficient than the straight-forward approach could try to make use of the fact that both maps use the same order. Unfortunately, the `map::insert` that takes a hint does not return whether or not the element could be found (if it did, you could try making use of the former target element as the hint for the next one).

Comment: Sketch of a best-case `O(N+M)` algorithm: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0932b4743edf9824 I might be confused about the hint/insertion position, though.

Answer (score 4):

```
template <class M>
void add_maps(M const& source, M& dest)
{
    for (auto const& entry : source)
        dest[entry.first] += entry.second;
}
```

Comment: Since the arguments are not treated equivalently, I'd rather choose names that reflect this.

Comment: @dyp Agree. What names do you suggest?

Comment: what would `auto` be here in case of map ?

Comment: @MistyD `std::map<K, V>::value_type`, or in other words, `std::pair<K, V>`.

Comment: I might call the function `add` or `sum` or something related that shows that it's adding up elements (if they exist in both maps). As per the OP's requirements, one `map` is not changed, the other is changed in-place. So one could be called a `source`, the other one `dest`, if a `+=` is actually performed (the operation is: add the elements of `source` to the elements of `dest`).

Comment: @dyp How does it look now?

Comment: Like `memcpy` ;) I prefer having the `dest` as the second parameter as in `std::copy` or `std::transform`.

Comment: @dyp Here you go. :-)

Comment: @MistyD and now, since I've changed the template to use `M` for the whole map rather than `K` and `V`, the type of the `auto` is now `typename M::value_type`. :-P